# about giving same column name in every table of database

Tags: mysql

I have a database with 5 tables. In every table there is a column for checking status. If i give the name to that column which is same in all the 5 tables; What will happen? Is it correct according to conventions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's perfectly correct, I have tens of tables and all of them do have createdon, createdby, modifiedon, modifiedby columns.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct.

The only thing to remember is that you'll need to prefix your field name if you join tables in a request :

```
SELECT a.status,
       b.status
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON ...
WHERE ...
```